# Best way persist this JSON data for use in a UITableView in iOS 6

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

My server is sending me a JSON response as follows:

```
[
  {
    "fields": {
      "message": "Major Network Problems", 
      "message_detail": "This is a test message"
    }, 
    "model": "notification", 
    "pk": 5
  }, 
  {
    "fields": {
      "message": "test", 
      "message_detail": "Some content"
    }, 
    "model": "notification", 
    "pk": 4
  }, 
  {
    "fields": {
      "message": "Test Message", 
      "message_detail": "Testing testing"
    }, 
    "model": "notification", 
    "pk": 3
  }
]
```

I want to populate a UITableView with a row per item just showing the value of the field `message` and then I'll tap that row to reveal a new view containing the `message` and `message_detail` values.  These messages may be updated at a later date where the `pk` value would be maintained so it's probably important to keep that information.

What's the most appropriate and efficient way of parsing this data and persisting it so it remains for the next launch of the app?

I'm thinking a plist would be a good way but I'd like to see some suggestions including some code on how best to go from the JSON array supplied to populating a UITableView and keeping the data for the next launch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have some class property:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *array;
@end
```

Just use `NSJSONSerialization`:

```
NSError *error;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
self.array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                             options:0
                                               error:&error];
```

If you want to save the array in your `Documents` folder for persistent storage for retrieval upon a future invocation of the app, you can:

```
NSString *docsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *filename = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"results.plist"];
[self.array writeToFile:filename atomically:NO];
```

To read it from the file later at the next invocation (in case you didn't want to re-retrieve it from the server):

```
NSString *docsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *filename = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"results.plist"];
self.array = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filename];
```

To use it for a `UITableView`, you'd store that in a class property and respond to the appropriate `UITableViewDataSource` methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.array count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    NSDictionary *rowData = self.array[indexPath.row];
    NSDictionary *fields = rowData[@"fields"];

    cell.textLabel.text = fields[@"message"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = fields[@"message_detail"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:' using your example above.  I can see that the text textLabel and detailTextLabel values are set correctly using NSLog, not sure what else to look for...

Comment: cell is nil, that's the problem, I'm not sure why

Comment: @conorgriffin You need to either (a) define cell prototype in Interface Builder with the correct cell identifier and then `dequeue...` will always return valid cell; or (b) you have to test to see if `dequeue` returned `nil`, and if so,  manually create a cell programmatically if one was not successfully dequeued. I would generally advise using cell prototypes (esp if doing complicated cell layouts), but either works.